# If I modify a column type, do I need to replace the corresponding view?

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Say I have the table :

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
  `IDTable` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` LONG
);
```

with view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `ViewTable` AS SELECT
  `table`.`IDTable` ,
  `table`.`date`
FROM
`table`;
```

If I eventually modify the column date from long to datetime, do I then need to rerun the create or replace view?

Comment: Tested it, no you don't have to refresh view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can leave your view alone.  The types are effectively pass through for a view.  The MySQL documentation found at [MySQL View Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) provides additional detail in regards to your inquiry.  However, I will note that the documentation from MySQL states that a view is considered "frozen" when it is created (3rd paragraph).  So you simply need to be aware that if you add a new column to any table you are referencing in the view, and you intend to use that column in the view, then you will need to replace it.